# Xamarin forms: How to access "tabBarController: shouldSelectViewController:"

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I need to have control of this method so that I can make a change in my app. But I couldn't make this implementation work, can anyone help?

Here is the Custom Renderer of my TabbedPage:

```
public class MainTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer, IUITabBarControllerDelegate
{
     [Export("tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:")]
     public bool ShouldSelectViewController(UITabBarController tabBarController, UIViewController viewController)
     {
          return false;
     }
}
```

The breakpoint does not stop there at all.

I have the impression that it does not stop at breakpoint because TabBarController is always null, but the screen loads and performs navigations normally, I also could not make this TabBarController be filled.

You can click on tabbar items using this method:

```
[Export("tabBar:didSelectItem:")]
public void ItemSelected(UITabBar tabbar, UITabBarItem item)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see where you are assigning your delegate. That  is likely why it is not hit, you have not assigned the delegate to the UITabBarController (which is the base class for TabbedRenderer). Also TabbedRenderer already assigns a delegate, so you likely do not want to replace it.

That said, Xamarin.iOS actually defines a [C# delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/UIKit.UITabBarSelection?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12), called `UITabBarSelection`,  for the `ShouldSelectViewController` protocol method. And there is a property on `TabbedRenderer` called `ShouldSelectViewController` that allows you to set this delegate method, so you should be able to just do this:

```
public class MainTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
          this.ShouldSelectViewController = ShouldSelectViewControllerHandler;
    }

    bool ShouldSelectViewControllerHandler(UITabBarController tabBarController, UIViewController viewController)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: ShouldSelectViewController is a method, why can't you put a value as you answered in the answer, something could be implemented wrong, can you supplement your answer with more pieces of code?

Comment: There is a property on the `TabbedRenderer` type called `ShouldSelectViewController`, and the type is `UITabBarSelection` which is a C# delegate. So you can assign a method with the same signature as the C# delegate to that property.  I tested the above and it works as expected.

Comment: please, put in your response

Comment: My answer is complete and works as written. Perhaps you are getting confused between Obj-C delegates and C# delegates. IN Obj-C, a delegate is usually a protocol (similar to a C# interface) and is an object used to handle events from the object that uses that protocol (Obj-C delegate), whereas a C# delegate is just a definition of a method signature and can be used as the type for a C# property such that you can assign a method to a property, as above. Read up on C# delegates if you need more info.

Comment: I need a solution that runs every time I click the tabbar buttons, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, see the above answer. I tested this. That method runs every time I click the tab bar, and returning false does make it so the new tab is not selected, or rather the view controller is NOT shown.

Comment: If it is not working for you, explain what is happening.

Comment: Ok, I'm testing!

Comment: Oh, you need to remove the `IUITabBarControllerDelegate` inheritance as that defines a method called `ShouldSelectViewController` which conflicts with the property name, so it confuses things. That may be why you said that `ShouldSelectViewController` is a method and can't be assigned. But you see my answer did remove that from the beginning.

Comment: oh yeah! Thanks man, works perfect! hehe I'll put your response on Xamarin forum, can you put in there?

Comment: Oh, I see that: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/145051/cancel-itemselected-event-in-tabbarrenderer-xamarin-ios#latest . ColeX is dong the same thing, just using a lambda rather than a named method. The end result is exactly the same though.